# nginx and SSL config

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, web-server

Can nginx be used with SSL?I am using http://nginxcp.com/ for my CPanel server and here are my config file setups

```
server {
          error_log /var/log/nginx/vhost-error_log warn;
          listen 1.2.3.4:80;
          server_name domina.org www.domina.org domina2.info www.domina2.info;
          access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/domina.org-bytes_log bytes_log;
          access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/domina.org combined;
          root /home/domina/public_html;
          location / {
          location ~.*\.(3gp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|html|htm|txt|js|css|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso)$ {
          expires 7d;
          try_files $uri @backend;
          }
          error_page 405 = @backend;
          add_header X-Cache "HIT from Backend";
          proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
          }
          location @backend {
          internal;
          proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
          }
          location ~ .*\.(php|jsp|cgi|pl|py)?$ {
          proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
          }
          location ~ /\.ht {
          deny all;
          }
        }
```

how do I get SSL added?

Answer (score 1):

Of course Nginx can handle HTTPS requests !

```
server {
   listen                   443;
   server_name              secure.mydomain.com;
   ssl                      on;
   ssl_certificate          /home/mydomain/conf/cert/chained_mydomain.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key      /home/mydomain/conf/cert/private_unlocked.pem;
   keepalive_timeout        50;
}
```

Here the official documentation about HttpSSL module: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule